# How Does Wordpress Remember Metabox Positions?

Tags: metabox

I was wondering how Wordpress remembers the position of metaboxes: session basis, user basis, computer basis? Does it set a cookie? Is it saved in the database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WordPress saves them in the databas in wp_usermeta as serilized array.
For the dashboard all are registered in **meta-box-order_dashboard** if the meta-box(s) are in **metaboxhidden_dashboard** they will *not* be shown. The order will be as saved in database and if not in **metaboxhidden_dashboard**.

Example the dashboard:

**KEY**: meta-box-order_dashboard

**VALUE**:

```
Array
(
   [normal] => dashboard_right_now,dashboard_recent_comments,dashboard_incoming_links,dashboard_plugins
   [side] => dashboard_quick_press,dashboard_recent_drafts,dashboard_primary,dashboard_secondary
   [column3] => 
   [column4] => 
)
```

**There are also these meta_key(s):**

- meta-box-order_dashboard
- metaboxhidden_dashboard
- meta-box-order_page
- metaboxhidden_page
- metaboxhidden_nav-menus
- meta-box-order_{custom_post}